# Crash log in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect, crash-reports

Apologies for my ignorance, I've tried searching around but couldn't find an answer.

I've recently tried uploading my app onto the app store but Apple came back saying the app crashes on launch and attached the crash log.

I've tried symbolicating the crash log by dragging the log into Xcode -> Windows -> Devices -> View Device Logs

Part of the snippet is returned as follows:

```
{"app_name":"WhoDat","timestamp":"2018-01-05 14:25:21.23 -0800","app_version":"1.14","slice_uuid":"dc778fa9-d896-3a05-8368-acb64cf12d9b","adam_id":1257412293,"build_version":"1","bundleID":"com.LemonIncLtd.WhoDat","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 11.2.1 (15C153)","incident_id":"E0FDE51B-95AB-45AA-B5EB-CB652E7E338C","name":"WhoDat"}
Incident Identifier: E0FDE51B-95AB-45AA-B5EB-CB652E7E338C
CrashReporter Key:   d6f3d39997ded4731aaf57ef5f7fc62b95e6d3ca
Hardware Model:      xxx1
Process:             WhoDat [2944]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1E7CF751-A823-421A-A987-FA889AAFBF97/WhoDat.app/WhoDat
Identifier:          com.LemonIncLtd.WhoDat
Version:             1 (1.14)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.LemonIncLtd.WhoDat [1678]


Date/Time:           2018-01-05 14:25:21.1369 -0800
Launch Time:         2018-01-05 14:25:16.9867 -0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.2.1 (15C153)
Baseband Version:    n/a
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000010446110c
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  10

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001848e7568 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001848e73e0 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184d9e308 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184d9bed4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184cbbe58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5   GraphicsServices                0x0000000186b68f84 GSEventRunModal + 100
6   UIKit                           0x000000018e33b67c UIApplicationMain + 236
7   WhoDat                          0x000000010445a70c 0x104454000 + 26380
8   libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001847d856c start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184908d80 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1aeec _pthread_wqthread + 884
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1ab6c start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184908d80 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1aeec _pthread_wqthread + 884
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1ab6c start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1ab68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001848e7568 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001848e73e0 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184d9e308 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184d9bed4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184cbbe58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5   Foundation                      0x00000001856f1594 -[NSRunLoop+ 50580 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   Foundation                      0x00000001857109ac -[NSRunLoop+ 178604 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96
7   UIKit                           0x000000018eea57b8 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8   Foundation                      0x00000001857f30f4 __NSThread__start__ + 996
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1c2b4 _pthread_body + 308
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1c180 _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1ab74 thread_start + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184908d80 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1aeec _pthread_wqthread + 884
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1ab6c start_wqthread + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1ab68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1ab68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001848e7568 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001848e73e0 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184d9e308 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184d9bed4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184cbbe58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5   CFNetwork                       0x00000001855ab128 -[__CoreSchedulingSetRunnable runForever] + 780
6   Foundation                      0x00000001857f30f4 __NSThread__start__ + 996
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1c2b4 _pthread_body + 308
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1c180 _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1ab74 thread_start + 4

Thread 9 name:  NetworkLoad
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001848e7568 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001848e73e0 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184d9e308 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184d9bed4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184cbbe58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5   GeoServices                     0x000000018aeef0ec _runNetworkThread + 468
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1c2b4 _pthread_body + 308
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1c180 _pthread_body + 0
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1ab74 thread_start + 4

Thread 10 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.background-qos
Thread 10 Crashed:
0   WhoDat                          0x000000010446110c 0x104454000 + 53516
1   WhoDat                          0x000000010446e230 0x104454000 + 107056
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184772a54 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184772a14 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018477fea4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1032
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018477fa38 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 120
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1b06c _pthread_wqthread + 1268
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1ab6c start_wqthread + 4

Thread 11 name:  com.apple.vectorkit.dispatch.layoutqueue
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001848e75bc semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184775000 _dispatch_sema4_timedwait$VARIANT$mp + 84
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184775870 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 72
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001847811d8 _dispatch_worker_thread + 256
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1c2b4 _pthread_body + 308
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1c180 _pthread_body + 0
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1ab74 thread_start + 4

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001848e75bc semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184775000 _dispatch_sema4_timedwait$VARIANT$mp + 84
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184775870 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 72
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001847811d8 _dispatch_worker_thread + 256
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1c2b4 _pthread_body + 308
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1c180 _pthread_body + 0
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1ab74 thread_start + 4

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184908d80 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1aeec _pthread_wqthread + 884
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1ab6c start_wqthread + 4

Thread 14 name:  com.squareup.SocketRocket.NetworkThread
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001848e7568 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001848e73e0 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184d9e308 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184d9bed4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184cbbe58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5   Foundation                      0x00000001856f1594 -[NSRunLoop+ 50580 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   WhoDat                          0x0000000104560028 0x104454000 + 1097768
7   Foundation                      0x00000001857f30f4 __NSThread__start__ + 996
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1c2b4 _pthread_body + 308
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1c180 _pthread_body + 0
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1ab74 thread_start + 4

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1ab68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 16 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184908534 __select + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184da6840 __CFSocketManager + 644
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1c2b4 _pthread_body + 308
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1c180 _pthread_body + 0
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1ab74 thread_start + 4

Thread 17 name:  com.apple.mapdisplay.iconrenderqueue
Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001848e75bc semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184775000 _dispatch_sema4_timedwait$VARIANT$mp + 84
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184775870 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 72
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001847811d8 _dispatch_worker_thread + 256
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1c2b4 _pthread_body + 308
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1c180 _pthread_body + 0
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a1ab74 thread_start + 4

Thread 10 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000105630380   x1: 0x000000018f06a470   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000001
    x4: 0x0000000000000001   x5: 0x0000000000000001   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x0000000000000001   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0x000000a7000000ff
   x12: 0x00000001058faf00  x13: 0x000005a104a8700f  x14: 0x0000000000000004  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000104a87008  x17: 0x000000018ee01ea8  x18: 0xfffffff01609925c  x19: 0x00000001c042cfe0
   x20: 0x0000000000000000  x21: 0x0000000105630380  x22: 0x0000000000000001  x23: 0x0000000000000000
   x24: 0xffffffffffffffff  x25: 0x0000000fffffc0c0  x26: 0x00000000ff00ffff  x27: 0x00000001b5927ab0
   x28: 0x00000001b5927ad0   fp: 0x000000016bf1edb0   lr: 0x00000001044610b4
    sp: 0x000000016bf1ed90   pc: 0x000000010446110c cpsr: 0x20000000
```

Could someone direct me and tell me how to read the above and find where the issue is occuring?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will need to symbolicate this crashlog before anyone can even begin to figure out what's wrong.  Look at thread 10 which crashed, `0x000000010446110c 0x104454000 + 53516` is not symbolicated.

Comment: I've dragged the crash report into: Xcode -> Windows -> Devices -> View Device Logs to symbolicate it... am I missing a step?

Comment: Are you using the correct dSYM file?  Did you make the store build with the mac that you're trying to symbolicate on?  Do you use Bitcode?  Did you download the latest dSYM from iTunes Connect?

Comment: The first thing I notice is that it's a background thread (background-qos) that has crashed so start looking there.